# Which yocto is best for me

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, yocto, bsp

I am new to yocto. and working on imx6ul board. There is a different type of yocto BSP like Morty, jethro, fido etc.

I want to use BSP with qt lgpl(not GPL) & Dynamic library.
How can differentiate them and can decide which one is best for my application?
Help to me to sort out this.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morty, Jethro, Fido etc. are not different "yoctos", but different [releases](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases) given the timeline of the project. Generally, pick the most current that is available, as it is the most actively maintained one. (At the current moment in time, Rocko is the stable release)